# Unable to delete a Mongodb document with Alamofire

Tags: swift, mongodb, alamofire

OK have being building an app in swift using both Mongodb and Alamofire, everything is working except the ability to delete a record.

I can add documents using:

```
    let studentCourseInfo = [
        "course_id": courseText.text!,
        "student_id": defaults.stringForKey(defaultsKeys.keyOne)!
    ]

Alamofire.request(.POST, 
        "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/XXXX/collections/iOS_app_enrollment?apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        parameters: studentCourseInfo, encoding: .JSON) 
       .response { (request, response, data, error) in
    }
```

I want to be able to also delete this record. I cannot find anything that gives examples an using Alamofire with MongoDB and deleting records. I have tried simply changing the POST to DELETE but it has no effect.

I cannot delete documents using:

```
    let studentCourseInfo = [
        "course_id": courseText.text!,
        "student_id": defaults.stringForKey(defaultsKeys.keyOne)!
    ]

Alamofire.request(.DELETE, 
        "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/XXXX/collections/iOS_app_enrollment?apiKey= XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        parameters: studentCourseInfo, encoding: .JSON) 
       .response { (request, response, data, error) in
    }
```

So naturally I am assuming there is something I am missing to get mongodb to play nice.
I have tried to use the same parameters as I used in creation, I have tried using the $id mongo creates. Hard coding to a specific record, nothing will delete the document.

Comment: None of my Alamofire DELETE have ever worked... Idk if it's an AF issue